# Grid columns inside a container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using grid to display 4 columns, but for some reason I can't use justify-content: space-between on them.

Example code:

```
<div class"wrapper">
 <div class"columns">
  <div class"column1"></div>
  <div class"column2"></div>
  <div class"column3"></div>
  <div class"column4"></div>
 </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

What am I achieving right now:
[RIGHT NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVYtD.png)

What I want to achieve:
[ACHIEVMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaKWG.png)

! Pay attention: 1) Displaying items as flex and justify space between is not a solution for me, because I want to use grid.
                 2) Giving columns grid-gap is also not a solution for me.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Since you've defined the columns with `1fr`, they consume all space on the row, and there's no extra space for separation. Hence, `justify-content` can't work.

Comment: If you give the columns a smaller total width than the width of the container, then `justify-content: space-between` will work. `(width of container) - (width of all columns) > 0`.  https://jsfiddle.net/fo6ht851/

Comment: So how should I fix my problem? Remember I want to use css grid and I want columns aligned from wrapper start to end with equal space between. I do not want to add custom grid-gap.

Comment: What you're asking for is contradictory: you do not want a gap between your columns, yet you want them to have space distributed equally between the columns?

Comment: Well if my wrapper is 1200 max width and I do the column width to 250px. 1000:4=250px for column. And I add 50px as grid gap (4x50=200 the rest px) it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin's solution did not involve specifying a custom grid gap

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin you did not, but you also did not used my wrapper, which is 1200px..if you set the width of the column to 1200:4=300px you achieve the same result as my first picture.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e3rg2thp/1/

Comment: The width of the wrapper equals the width of all columns. Why would it work? It doesn't leave extra space.